# Get Gradle daemon to run on specific Java version

Tags: java, gradle, version, daemon

This is running Gradle 5.2.1 in Cygwin BASH on a Windows 10 OS.

There are a few answers about getting Gradle to use a certain JDK and JRE. My system is using Java 9 (in the sense that JAVA_HOME points to its JDK, and the first entry for PATH to its \bin directory)... but for a particular project using TestFX I have to use Java 8.

I have spent hours trying to get things to work but I always come up against this problem.  Output:

> $ ./gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=D:/apps/Java/jdk1.8.0_191
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon, 20 busy and 2 incompatible Daemons could not
>   be reused, use --status for details
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected. It won't be possible to reconnect to this
>     daemon. Context mismatch: Java home is different. 
>   Wanted:
>     DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=D:\apps\Java\jdk1.8.0_191,daemonRegistryDir=D:\apps\gradle\gradle-5.2.1\gradle_user_home\daemon,pid=8736,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=GB,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
>     Actual:
>     DefaultDaemonContext[uid=12195e35-1c39-45d6-8abe-bdeebeea4d37,javaHome=D:\apps\Java\jre1.8.0_201,daemonRegistryDir=D:\apps\gradle\gradle-5.2.1\gradle_user_home\daemon,pid=10500,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=GB,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]

The thing that is baffling me is this bit for the "Actual" daemon: "javaHome=D:\apps\Java\jre1.8.0_201".

There is indeed a JRE at that location... but at no point in my system do I say or does anyone say it is a "java home" / "java.home" / JAVA_HOME or indeed, as printed here, javaHome.

Incidentally, I put ECHO statements in gradlew to tell me which JAVA_HOME and JAVACMD were going to be used.  These in fact show Java 9 paths, which is how my system is configured.  However it is clear that the directive to use Java 8 does work (works equally if I put this in gradle.properties), as the daemon which is eventually spun up is obviously running on Java 8.  But WHY or HOW is it finding this JRE path ... and then calling it "javaHome" / "java.home" / "JAVA_HOME" ?

Answer (score 0):

I regard this as a workaround as I really don't understand the mechanisms here.

I went to Oracle and downloaded the JDK 8u191 installation .exe and installed on my system.  Part of this process involves "component registration" and other stuff ... suffice to say that at the end of this the daemon incompatibility issue seems to have gone away.

Looking at my "Java" icon ("Java control panel"?) in the W10 Control Panel I found that nothing had changed: I have 3 versions of Java in the User tab: 11.0.2, 1.8.0_201 (unticked for Enabled) and 1.8.0_191.  In the System tab there is just one: 1.8.0_201 (unticked for Enabled).

The daemons appear to be being created by 1.8.0_191, which works because this is the same Java version as in the ./gradlew build directive.  Would still like to know how this all works though: configuring Java 8 seems to spur Gradle on to find some location that looks "about right for a Java 8 JDK".